# Convert Window desktop application into Window service

Tags: c#

I have a window desktop application, developed in C#.NET (.NET framework 4.0), but now I want to convert it into window services. There is one Window Form in desktop application. How is it possible? Any code or helping link is welcomed.

Thanks

Comment: how do you imagine the user to interact with the application once it runs as service and has no UI? or do you want to decouple and fully rewrite the UI or UI <-> service side communication layer?

Comment: How is a user going to use the app if it's a service? What do you want to do with the form? And if you still want to keep the form, why do you want the app to be a service?

Answer (score 3):

It entirely depends upon what the application does. The main thing you have to remember is that when an app is running as a service it cannot have any user interaction, as it runs unattended.

Take a look at this for more background:

[Introduction to Windows Service Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d56de412%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Or look at using SrvStart (a freeware utility) to run an existing app as a service:

[Using SrvStart to Run Any Application as a Windows Service](http://www.howtogeek.com/50786/using-srvstart-to-run-any-application-as-a-windows-service/)

There are also commercial tools that can convert Windows apps to run as services such as:

[FireDaemon](http://www.firedaemon.com/)

[AlwaysUp](http://www.coretechnologies.com/products/AlwaysUp/)

Answer (score 1):

Once an app is running as a service all comunication between a seprate UI presentation app is cross process - so you need to manage that.  Depending on your skill set probably the easiest way to do that today is WCF.  Your first step is to define the interface between the GUI client application and the service (what calls does GUI need to make on the serivice, are they oneway or duplex (return data), does the service need to trigger events client side (which requires a callback interface)? etc).
Once that is decided you can go ahead and start building your WCF service.  That is a dll that needs to be hosted - in your case by a service host - this is quite straight forward and there is plenty on infomation available about that (basically just a few lines of boiler plate code and then run a utility to register the service).  It is useful to test your server using a Command line host in place of the service host (easier to debug etc) - so worth while setting up 2 host projects (one service, one cmd line).
I've personally never tried a form client with a WCF service - if your form is simple you might find it easier to dev your client in WPF.  The client uses the interface you defined to make calls on the server and the WCF generated proxy code impliments that interface to manage the tranport accross process (or machine).  WCF is very flexible via configuration files about the transport to be used (namedpipes, tcp, http etc).  Bon courage!

Answer (score 1):

Ricibob's answer is correct. I started the way he suggested. I needed WCF Data Services because I had to edit some data in the db. And I got stuck when I found out that WCF Data Services doesn't support Enums. My business objects widely used enums and now I don't know what to do.